# Parse save() from the client gets changes done in beforeSave?

Tags: parse-platform

Using parse from an Ios/Android app, I create a new object of my class "Tomato" and call save() or saveInBackground(...).

In this class "Tomato" beforeSave hook, I initialise some fields with custom values.

My question is, are those values available in the client after the save is completed? Or do i need to fetch the object after save it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `fetch` it again to get access to the values created in `beforeSave` (note that `refresh` is deprecated and Parse now wants you to use `fetch`):

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetch:

Answer (score 0):

You have the updated object in the save callback:

```
gameScore.save(null, {
  success: function(object) {
    // The object was saved successfully.
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The save failed.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

**Android**

> ```
> ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
> gameScore.put("score", 1337);
> gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
> gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
> gameScore.saveInBackground();
> ```
>
> After this code runs, you will probably be wondering if anything
>   really happened. To make sure the data was saved, you can look at the
>   Data Browser in your app on Parse. You should see something like this:
>
> ```
> objectId: "xWMyZ4YEGZ", score: 1337, playerName: "Sean Plott", cheatMode: false,
> createdAt:"2011-06-10T18:33:42Z", updatedAt:"2011-06-10T18:33:42Z"
> ```

Source: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-saving-objects

Comment: It looks like the callback for Javascript does contain the object. But the callbacks for IOS/Android dont. ¿Any idea about this situation on mobile SDKs ?

Comment: The question is not about the save itself, is about if the changes being done in beforeSave cloud hook are being pushed to the client or not.